# Eliminar evento del teclado asociado al objeto Window

Tags: javascript, eventos, onkeyup

Quiero crear un evento sobre el objeto Window que al soltar una tecla en este caso enter me incremente un contador, en caso de que ese contador llegue a 10 se elimina ese evento.
El problema es que funciona bien, al llegar al 10 deja de contar, pero sigue registrandome la tecla enter pero ahora lanzandome el error : "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" y dentro del elemento "boton2" (uso textContent para mostrar el contador en un div) me tira unos numeros extraños

```
const boton2 = document.querySelector(".boton2")
    
    let contador2 = 0
    let funcion2 = function(event){
        if(event.key=="Enter") contador2++;
        boton2.textContent = `${contador2}`
        if(contador2>10) removeEventListener("keyup",funcion2(event));
    }
    
    addEventListener("keyup",event => funcion2(event))
```

he probado muchas cosas pero estoy a ciegas, simplemente no se que esta ocurriendo. Si alguien sabe y me lo explica se lo agradeceria.

Answer (score 3):

Veo dos problemas. Cuando añades el event listener, lo hace así

```
addEventListener("keyup",event => funcion2(event))
```

Esto en realidad crea una función flecha, que es la que realmente estás registrando y luego esta llama a **función2**

Por otro lado, cuando eliminas el event listener, lo haces de esta manera

```
removeEventListener("keyup",funcion2(event));
```

Pretendes eliminar la escucha capturada por **funcion2**, pero como dije arriba, lo que registraste no es **funcion2** sino la función flecha. Por otro lado, tampoco estarías "des-registrando" la **funcion2**, sino lo que devuelve la **funcion2**, ya que al poner los paréntesis, lo que realmente estás haciendo es llamarla y pasándole a removeEventListener el valor devuelto.

Para solucionarlo, cambia el addEventListener por

```
addEventListener("keyup", funcion2)
```

Como ves, ahora estamos registrando la función. De igual manera, al eliminarla, cambia el removeEventListener por

```
removeEventListener("keyup",funcion2);
```

Y una última cosa, aunque no tiene nada que ver con lo anterior, si pretendes contar hasta 10, la comparación debería decir así

```
if(contador2 >= 10)
```

o bien

```
if(contador2 > 9)
```

ya que en caso contrario, al hacerse la comparación después de mostrar el dato, contaría hasta 11.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta! igual era una tonteria :( el div que muestra el contador antes era un input y me olvide de sacarle la propiedad type="button", se lo saque y ya me funciona bien no tuve que cambiar nada, gracias igual